# How to change default empty representative in forms CharField?

Tags: python, django, forms

I use an unbound form with BooleanField and CharField

None are required

but when empty, value in database is a representative empty string for Charfield and 0 for BooleanField

I would like NULL value instead but don't find how to set this.

```
class CreateForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["field1"] = forms.BooleanField(label = "", required = False, initial=None)
        self.fields["field2"] = forms.CharField(label = "", required = False, initial=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set empty values as null you can just add null=True to your field.

```
class CreateForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["field1"] = forms.BooleanField(label = "", required = False, initial=None, null=True)
        self.fields["field2"] = forms.CharField(label = "", required = False, initial=None, null=True)
```

Comment: thanks for replying ; nevertheless, null is not an option and got a TypeError at 

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'null'

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You can't set null or blank for form fields, it's reserved for models (and models forms). You shouldn't set null=True for CharField/TextField anyway.
Django advice:
"Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string."

Comment: yes, you are right, I've read that... but I need... I could manage this in my views: if form.cleaned_data['key'] == "": return None but it is probably dirty !!!